# Rails: redirecting from controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In my Rails 3.2 project, in my controller, I have a `show_html` function. If it can find a site with a particular URL in the database, it will pass that on to the view. Otherwise, I want it to redirect to http://www.google.com

```
def show_html
  site_list = Site.where(:url => params[:url])
  if site_list.length > 0
    site = site_list.first

  else
    redirect_to "http://www.google.com"
  end

  @html = site.html
  render "show_html.html.erb"

end
```

When I tested it and `site_list.length > 0`, it works. But when `site_length_list = 0`, it gives an error `undefined method 'html' for nil:NilClass`. Why doesn't it go into the `else` statement and render `google.com`?

Comment: in line 10, its looking for the `html` action which I guess is you dint declare anywhere inside your class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like instructions after redirects will be executed.  Here is an [article](http://blog.hulihanapplications.com/browse/view/60-rails-security-execute-after-redirect) referencing this problem.

One way to solve this problem is to `return` the redirect like so:

```
def show_html
  site_list = Site.where(:url => params[:url])
  if site_list.length > 0
    site = site_list.first

  else
    return redirect_to "http://www.google.com"
  end

  @html = site.html
  render "show_html.html.erb"

end
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need render (and site.html which is nil.html in else condition) after redirect. You need one of it.

```
def show_html
  site_list = Site.where(:url => params[:url])
  if site_list.length > 0
    site = site_list.first
    @html = site.html
    render "show_html.html.erb"
  else
    redirect_to "http://www.google.com"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't get into the `if`, your `site` will be `nil`.
And if you don't set `return` with the `redirect`, the function will just go all the way down, even if you don't have the nil error, you will probably get an other one with a redirect + a render.

A clean way to define your function

```
def show_html
  site_list = Site.where(:url => params[:url])

  return redirect_to "http://www.google.com" if site_list.empty?

  site = site_list.first
  @html = site.html
  render "show_html.html.erb"
end
```